# Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error. While Making a GET Request using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, backend

I am attempting to construct a simple web page and making a GET  Request  using Spring MVC, and I have encountered this issue.

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jan 10 14:25:35 IST 2024

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

No static resource webapp/WEB-INF/mypages/Home.jsp.

org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource webapp/WEB-INF/mypages/Home.jsp.

## Controller

```
package com.sample.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class HomeController{


    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String ShowHome(){
        return"Home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showShow(){
        return"Show";
    }

}
```

## **application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/WEB-INF/mypages/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

## **Home.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Wellcome to HomePage</h1>
    <h1>chick <a href="/show">Here</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## **Show.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>show page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Show Page</h1>
        <h1>move to <a href="/home">Register</a></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

## **Folder Structure**

### Folder Structure Image

[image]

### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to change `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/WEB-INF/mypages/` to `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/mypages/`

Comment: after  that change i faceing this issue                                                  
    Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jan 10 18:46:05 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
JSP file [/WEB-INF/mypages/Home.jsp] not found

Comment: Are you wanting to customize the error page, or avoid the error page altogether?